# Returning a char from a method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, char, return

I don't know what's wrong, but I can't get this method to return the characters I'm wanting it to. I just keep getting an error in the form of red lines under the word 'return'

Here's my method.

```
public static char getOperator(String fileContent){


    int checkAdd = fileContent.indexOf('+');
    int checkMinus = fileContent.indexOf('-');
    int checkMulti = fileContent.indexOf('*');
    int checkDivi = fileContent.indexOf('/');

    if (checkAdd != -1){
        return char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('+')); 
    }   
    else if (checkMinus != -1) {
        return char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('-'));
    }
    else if (checkMulti != -1) {
        return char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('*'));
    }
    else if (checkDivi != -1){
        return char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('/'));
    }
    return 0;


    }
```

Okay, sorry about that, I had been messing with it in eclipse and didn't catch that issue. However, now the return statements in the ifs still produce errors. How do I fix that?

Comment: Your function returns void 'public static void getOperator()'

Comment: public static void getOperator(){}... and you expecting it to return anything?

Comment: replace the return. You're currently returning a number not a char; `return ' ';`

Comment: I'm still getting errors on the returns in the if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
public static char getOperator(String fileContent){

    int checkAdd = fileContent.indexOf('+');
    int checkMinus = fileContent.indexOf('-');
    int checkMulti = fileContent.indexOf('*');
    int checkDivi = fileContent.indexOf('/');

    if (checkAdd != -1){
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(checkAdd); 
        return operator;
    }   
    else if (checkMinus != -1) {
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(checkMinus);
        return operator;
    }
    else if (checkMulti != -1) {
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(checkMulti);
        return operator;
    }
    else if (checkDivi != -1){
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(checkDivi);
        return operator;
    }

    return ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the method signature...

```
public static void getOperator(){
```

States that the method does not return anything.

Instead it should be declared more like...

```
public static char getOperator(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're return method is void, not char, so you cant return a value.